# Copy random row from one Google Sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 separate google sheets.
(Lets call them Primary and Secondary)

The Primary spreadsheet has 2 columns with 50 rows of data.

On a set interval (weekly) I want to copy only one random row from the Primary spreadsheet and add it as a new row in the Secondary spreadsheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Copy a random single row from 1 google sheet to another on a scheduled basis](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/131911736).

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper sheet that shows a random row from the Primary sheet using `filter()` and `randbetween()`, together with a time-driven script such as [appendValuesToArchiveSheet](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/27095918?msgid=27163801).

Comment: I realise this is the answer from the duplicate asked by the OP at [Doc Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/131911736/copy-a-random-single-row-from-1-google-sheet-to-another-on-a-scheduled-basis) but it also seems like a "code only" answer.

Answer (score 0):

*On a set interval (weekly) I want to copy only one random row from the Primary spreadsheet and add it as a new row in the Secondary spreadsheet.* Yes this is possible. There are likely to be many possible solutions, consider this as one approach.

The answer requires a script. There are many precedents that provide one or more elements of the solution, but none that wrap them into a cohesive whole.

The script `appendrandomRow` must be installed as an Installable Time-Driven, running once a week.

```
function appendrandomRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  // define the sheets
  var primary = ss.getSheetByName('Primary')
  var secondary = ss.getSheetByName('Secondary')

  // get the data from Primary
  var rangetoLog = primary.getDataRange()
  var valuestoLog = rangetoLog.getValues()

  // get last row by using 'length'
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of entries = "+valuestoLog.length)
  
  // or get last row by counting values
  // Note started at A2 to avoid header
  var lastRow = primary.getRange("A2:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of data rows = "+lastRow)
 
  // subroutine to get Random Integer
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
  // Getting a random integer between two values
  // Min is inclusive so set to 1
  // Max is exclusive so add "2" 
  var min = Math.ceil(1);
  var max = Math.floor(lastRow+2);
  var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the random row = "+randomRow+ ", values: "+valuestoLog[randomRow-1][0]+", "+valuestoLog[randomRow-1][1])
 
  // create a temporary array to hold the values from the random row
  var temparray=[]
  // push the values into the atemporary array
  temparray.push(valuestoLog[randomRow-1][0])
  temparray.push(valuestoLog[randomRow-1][1])

  // append the data to the 'Secondary' sheet
  secondary.appendRow(temparray)

}
```

---